# I can't import fixture into my fitnesse page

Tags: java, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I wanted to begin test my Java Apps with Fitnesse, but I have a big problems right at beginning.

My fitnesse page to test my very simple class is:

```
!contents -R2 -g -p -f -h
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path /home/user/NetBeansProjects/dotestow/build/classes/dotestow/


!|dodawanie|
|l1|l2|add?|
|10|2|12|
|10|35|45|
|60|4|33|
```

My class is just normal Java class created by NetBeans, here is the code:

```
package dotestow;

public class Dotestow {

    private int l1, l2;

    public void setL1(int l1) {this.l1 = l1;}
    public void setL2(int l2) {this.l2 = l2;}

    public int add()
    {
      return l1+l2;
    }
}
```

When I click test, it just shows:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fitnesse/slim/SlimService
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fitnesse.slim.SlimService
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: fitnesse.slim.SlimService. Program will exit.
```

What am I doing wrong??

@@EDIT

When I run

```
java Dotestow
```

in my /Dotestow/build/classes directory, i got output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Dotestow (wrong name:      dotestow/Dotestow)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Dotestow. Program will exit.
```

Comment: What version of FitNesse are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer Updated**

Looks like `FitNesse.jar` is missing from the classpath or JRE missmatch with the FitNesse jar version. Please check if `Fitnesse.jar` is added to classpath in netbeans.

Regards,

Comment: I did it, but it didn't help. I dont know if problm is in path or in my java code..

Comment: Can you try 1 thing, open console window and try running using java command "java -classpath . dotestow.Dotestow". Run this command from your compiled class root dir. This will make sure your class is not corrupted.

Comment: I got output: `Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32   use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64   use a 64-bit data model if available`
... and more of it... But check my edit, please.

Comment: Your error is justifiable. Because you are running it wrong. You need to run exactly how I said in my previous comment. Where is the directory where your classes are compiled ? Is it classes dir ? If yes then navigate to classes and then run >> java -classpath . dotestow.Dotestow

Comment: I got it now : ) When I run this command i get error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`, but when I'll add `public static void main(String[] args) {}` in my class code - my class is launched with the command you provided me. What now? : ]

Comment: That's it, this is your problem >> absence of main in your code. Add main method and run from Netbeans. Should be fine.

Comment: I can run it in NetBeans - just still can't run my test in FitNesse :/

Comment: Ok, please check netbeans settings and see if FitNesse.jar is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly add `fitnesse.jar` to your classpath using `!path`, giving the full absolute path to the .jar

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`!path /home/user/NetBeansProjects/dotestow/build/classes/dotestow/`

for this

`!path /home/user/NetBeansProjects/dotestow/build/classes/
|Import|
|dotestow|`

**or**

remove (from your Class)

> package dotestow;

and use **javac** to complile :D